# What is the best way/design to handle touches as well UICollectionViewDelegate methods

Tags: uicollectionview, uitouch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have functioning UICollectionView controller with my own UICollectionView subclass and cells etc.

1)Now I decided to add slideView as explained in http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path behind by own collectionview controller.
2) Then I wasnt happy enough since it doesnt give me "peak-inside" feel as FaceBook app on iOS

3) So then I modified code and handle touches in my own collectionView subclass. After going thru this site and some initial struggle I can now get the same feel like FB

4) But in the process of handling touches I lost the UICollectionViewDelegate didSelectItemAtIndePath. They never get called because of touch.

5) So I added tapGesture on collectionView in my storyboard and hooked everything up and made explicit call

```
- (IBAction)selectCellWithSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"SELECT");
    CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:tapLocation];
    if (indexPath) {
        [self collectionView:self.collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

1)Now IS this the correct approach?
2)If not what is the better design?
3)I also like to know what this method does selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: in UICollectionView could I use this one?